# How to delete a node from json file with php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have the next json:

```
[
    {
        "clave": "es",
        "content": {
            "barra": [
                "a",
                "a",
                "N",
                "C"
            ],
            "letras_inicio": "a",
            "titulos_servicios": [
                "A",
                "A",
                "A"
            ],
            "desc_servicios": [
                "O",
                "O",
                "E"
            ],
            "titulo_nosotros": "n",
            "descripcion_nosotros": "S",
            "titulos_especialidades": [
                "A",
                "A"
            ],
            "desc_especialidades": [
                "E",
                "L"
            ],
            "titulo_frm_contacto": "Co",
            "frmContacto": [
                "N",
                "c",
                "C",
                "A",
                "M",
                "E"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "clave": "por",
        "content": {
            "barra": [
                "f",
                "f",
                "f",
                "f"
            ],
            "letras_inicio": "f",
            "titulos_servicios": [
                "f",
                "f",
                "f"
            ],
            "desc_servicios": [
                "qf",
                "qf",
                "qf"
            ],
            "titulo_nosotros": "f",
            "descripcion_nosotros": "qf",
            "titulos_especialidades": [
                "f",
                "f"
            ],
            "desc_especialidades": [
                "qf",
                "qf"
            ],
            "titulo_frm_contacto": "f",
            "frmContacto": [
                "f",
                "f",
                "f",
                "f",
                "f",
                "f"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The next code is that i use to delete a node from json file:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$index = filter_var($obj->index);
$data = file_get_contents('languajes.json');
$data = json_decode($data,true);
unset($data[$index]);
if($data = json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)){
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
file_put_contents('languajes.json', $data);
```

So, when I save the json it looks like:

```
{
    "0": {
        "clave": "es",
        "content": {
            "barra": [
                "I",
                "S",
                "N",
                "C"
            ],
            "letras_inicio": "N",
            "titulos_servicios": [
                "A",
                "A",
                "A"
            ],
            "desc_servicios": [
                "O",
                "O",
                "E"
            ],
            "titulo_nosotros": "N",
            "descripcion_nosotros": "S",
            "titulos_especialidades": [
                "A",
                "A"
            ],
            "desc_especialidades": [
                "E",
                "L"
            ],
            "titulo_frm_contacto": "C",
            "frmContacto": [
                "N",
                "A",
                "C",
                "A",
                "M",
                "E"
            ]
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "clave": "en",
        "content": {
            "barra": [
                "H",
                "S",
                "A",
                "C"
            ],
            "letras_inicio": "W",
            "titulos_servicios": [
                "W",
                "M",
                "D"
            ],
            "desc_servicios": [
                "W",
                "W",
                "W"
            ],
            "titulo_nosotros": "A",
            "descripcion_nosotros": "W",
            "titulos_especialidades": [
                "W",
                "m"
            ],
            "desc_especialidades": [
                "f",
                "a"
            ],
            "titulo_frm_contacto": "C",
            "frmContacto": [
                "F",
                "L",
                "E",
                "S",
                "M",
                "S"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when y try to read the data after save the data in json file, the number that php put it causes that I can't read the file.
how can I avoid that this happen?

I will be to grateful for your answers

Comment: What data are you passing from the AJAX Call

Comment: reset the index, `file_put_contents('languajes.json', array_values($data));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unset()` just removes an index from an array, it doesn't adjust the indexes of all the other elements. When an array's indexes aren't sequential numbers starting at `0`, `json_encode()` encodes it as an object, not an array.

After unsetting, you can reset all the indexes with

```
$data = array_values($data);
```

Or you can use `array_splice()` to remove the element:

```
array_splice($data, $index, 1);
```